# How to open google assistant in Android TV Emulator

Tags: android, adb, voice-recognition, android-tv, google-assistant

I'm working with the voice assistant, but I'm not sure how I can open the google assistant in the Android TV Emulator.

I was able to setup my microphone, and it's working when I open the google assistant in the android tv home. However, I want to open it while using my app. If it was a real tv, I would have the mic or assistant button on the remote controller, but in this case I just have the emulator.

An ADB command to trigger it would also help.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `adb` command should work specifying the Assistant component

```
adb shell am start-activity com.google.android.apps.googleassistant/.AssistantActivity
```

Comment: Hey Diego, thanks for your answer.
I tried that, but I got Error type 3 Activity class does not exist. 
I assumed that I don't have to declare anything related to it in my project manifest, as I'm trying to start an OS activity.

Comment: Yes, that's completely independent of your project. Try `adb shell cmd package list packages`

Comment: Did that but I couldn't find anything close to com.google.android.apps.googleassistant in the list. Do you want me to update the post with the packages list?

Comment: You can launch the assistant and check logcat (search for `START`) to see the intent

Comment: Awesome... I was able to launch it with the following command:
adb shell am start-activity com.google.android.katniss/com.google.android.apps.tvsearch.app.launch.trampoline.SearchActivityTrampoline

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gustavopeq cool!